# custom keyboard expands edittext to half of the screen

Tags: android

is there any way to avoid a custom keyboard resizing my edittext to half of the screen.

is use this command

```
               editTextKeyboard = new EditText(this);

    editTextKeyboard.requestFocus();
    editTextKeyboard.setAlpha(0);
    editTextKeyboard.setSingleLine();

    editTextKeyboard.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    //editTextKeyboard.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    addContentView(editTextKeyboard, layoutParamsCompleteLayout);
```

it also changes the alpha level.

would be glad for any support

Comment: plz vote up and accept if it fix your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use android:imeOptions:flagNoFullscreen in xml file or use editTextKeyboard.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN)

Here is link for reference
1)[link1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeOptions%28int%29)
2)[link2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions)

Comment: shame this requires API 11. mmmm

Comment: flagNoExtractUi is pretty OK for API level < 11